# GCM push notifications - Need to view all push alerts in the mobile notification area, one after the another.

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Please apologize if my question is too simple.

Currently I am working on an android app, in which I will receive multiple alerts (from a server) and I have to view all push alerts one after the another (in the mobile notifications list).

I have given my code below. My server is sending all GCM push alert notifications to my android phone successfully.

However, I was able to view only the push alert which was sent last (in the notifications list). That is, consider my server is sending 2 push alerts: PUSH_A and PUSH_B. In my android phone, I was able to view only the 2nd alert: PUSH_B.

Can you please say, what I have done wrong. I have to view all push alerts in mobile one after the another (PUSH_A and PUSH_B in Notifications list).

My **server code** is as follows:

```
Sender aGcmSender = new Sender(API_KEY); 

//Constructing message which need to be transmitted to android device.      
Message aMessage = new Message.Builder().addData("message", thePushMsg).build(); 

Result aResult = aGcmSender.send(aMessage, theRegId, 1); //Transmitting message to android device
if(aResult != null)
{
    if(aResult.getMessageId() != null)
    {
        String aCanonicalRegistrationId = aResult.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
        if(aCanonicalRegistrationId != null)
        {
            //updating aCanonicalRegistrationId to my database
        }
        itsLogger.info("Push notification successfully sent to cub of phone: "+theCubsPhone);
        itsLogger.info("Message Id:"+aResult.toString());
    }
    else 
    {  
        String error = aResult.getErrorCodeName();
        itsLogger.info("Android Push Notification: Failed to send push notification to phone" + thePushMsg);
        if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {    
            // application has been removed from device - unregister database
        }
    }
}
```

**GCM code in mobile:**
**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <permission android:name="MyProjectPackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="MyProjectPackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- BroadcastReceiver for push alert notifications -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="MyProjectPackage" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

**GCMIntentService:**

```
private void sendGCMIntent(final Context theContext, String theMessage) 
    {   
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                theContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, theMessage, when);

        String title = theContext.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(theContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(theContext, title, theMessage, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);    
    }
```

Any help please.

Thank You.

Comment: ensure you have different collapse key for each message that you send from your server. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your notification id is 0 always

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

The new notification will be replaced with the previous one. Just you have to change the id to any number like that :

```
if (theMessage.equals(PUSH_A ))
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
else
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For example I have said PUSH_A and PUSH_B. Consider that my server is sending 'n' number of alerts. How can I have my notificationManager to list all of the 'n' number of alerts. Help please.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Hatem. You are correct. To list the 'n' number of alerts, with different id's I used, (int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() as id... So notificationManager.notify((int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), notification); Thanks again

Comment: I think it has to do with collapse key

Comment: when i push multiple message it shows that many app icon on notification bar, i want to show one icon and counter. is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

put

```
int n_id =  new Random().nextInt();
```

pass this `n_id` to

```
mNotificationManager.notify(appName, n_id, mBuilder.build());
```

function
as i has passed it
hence, integer id will always get different random number and this ways always new notification will receive for each new message